# AngularJS Directive Applying Wrong Data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, highcharts

So I've written a custom directive in AngularJS that generates a HighCharts graph when the page is loaded.

The issue I'm having is that it is applying the data of two separate queries in the back end to all the graphs on the page rather than just the assigned one.

Am I missing something obvious here in my design?

Full code: https://github.com/matt-major/swordfish

Screenshot of the issue: http://postimg.org/image/lf7p69q4x/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to work this out after a little trial and error.

It appears that I was pulling in the incorrect scope in to my controller which was preventing me from only emitting/broadcasting on this scope.

Since change the scope (this is the only change that was made) the data is correctly bound to each element using this directive and the graphs are displaying correctly.

For those who are interested I was originally using

```
$scope.getData($scope.$parent.alert);
```

After changing this to be the below the issue is resolved.

```
$scope.getData($scope.$parent);
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't look into your code too much but it looks like you are passing the data to the graph in a 'render' event which is probably getting send to all of your directives. Instead of using events I would pass the data into your directive through an attribute. e.g.

JS

```
app.directive('chart', function () {
    return {
        scope: {
            series: '='
        },
        link: function (scope, element) {
            scope.$watch('series', function (newValue) {
                //Render the graph here
            }
        }
    }
}
```

HTML

```
<div chart series="ctrl.someData"></div>
```

Also here is a working example in a sample app I made https://github.com/robianmcd/angular-stocks/blob/master/client/components/stockChartDirective.js

You can see the app running at http://angular-stocks.herokuapp.com/#/details?symbol=GOOG